# How many lines is needed to determine another line in 3d space?

Tags: geometry

A line is determined so that it intersects several other lines. How many of these other lines is needed so that the line to be determined is unique?

I think that the answer is four, but I'm not smart enough to be sure.

Comment: Two points determine one line. Two crossing points determine one line. Two other lines crossing the first one will determine it.

Comment: It depends on what the lines are.  Consider the infinite collection of lines $\{\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3,\ell_4,\dots\}$ where $\ell_n$ is the line $\ell_n(t)=[t,n,0]$  (*alternatively phrased, the line where $z=0$ and $y=n$*).  Every one of these lines lie on the $x-y$ plane, and every non-vertical line from the $x-y$ plane will interesect each and every one of these so no number of lines from the collection will be enough to uniquely determine your desired line that intersects them all.

Comment: To clarify in case the comments so far are unclear, the answer to the question of "What is the smallest number of lines such that it is *possible* to uniquely determine a line that intersects all of them" is four.  The answer to the question of "What is the smallest number of lines such that it is *guaranteed* to be able to uniquely determine a line that intersects all of them" the answer is that no such minimum exists and it can be impossible to find a unique line that intersects them all either because there are always multiple such lines available or because no such line is available.